# Can I change XSLT 1.0 to round negative half numbers down instead of up? i.e. -2.5 to -3

Tags: xslt, xpath, rounding

XSLT 1.0 seems to round negative half numbers up instead of down (i.e. -2.5 to -2). Although it may seem less conventional, can I change it to round that to -3?

Is there a way to change this behavior (develop a new function, use a different function, supply parameters, etc), or do I have to use a template?

I wrote my own template already, but it makes my XSL much more messy than when it just included round functions.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="round(-2.5)"/>

  <xsl:call-template name="customRounding">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="-2.5"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="customRounding">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$input = ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$input &lt; 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="round($input * -1) * -1"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="round($input)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: I had previously said that rounding negative numbers up could be considered more correct than rounding them down. However, after more reading, I realize that rounding half numbers is ambiguous, and conventions vary.

Comment: For consistency, I think calling a template is your best bet, even if it is a bit verbose. The alternative would be to use a wrought-out, error-prone expression every time you need to do this operation (and even moreso if you need to account for the `''` -> `0` conversion you have going on there). Certain XSLT 1.0 platforms do allow creating your own custom functions and that could be a nice alternative, but you haven't mentioned what you're using to run your XSLT and each platform's implementation of custom functions is completely different.

Answer (score 2):

```
2*($num >= 0) - 1
```

will give you -1 if `$num` is negative, +1 otherwise (a Boolean expression in numeric context is 0 for false and 1 for true). Given this you can then do `round($sign * $num) * $sign` to get the result you're after. Not quite one function but it might be more succinct than a template call.

Comment: +1, nice use of *sign*. Another way to generate $sign = `($num > 0) - ($num &lt; 0)`. I like this better because then sign(0) = 0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I hadn't thought of that one, though in this case it makes no difference as you're multiplying the original number by its sign.

Answer (score -1):

You can prefer another behaviour: there are three XPath functions for "rounding" numbers:

- `floor(n)` - returns the next integer which is less than *n*. Ex: `floor(2.9) = 2`
- `ceiling(n)`  - returns the next integer which is larger than *n*. Ex: `ceiling(2.1) = 3`
- `round(n)` - rounds the number. Ex: `round(2.5) = 3`, `round(2.49999) = 2`, `round(-2.5) = -2`, `round(-2.50001) = -3`

To convert `-2.5` into `-3` use `floor(-2.5)`.

Comment: I need to maintain consistency with Oracle database's round function, where unfortunately round(-2.5)=-3 and round(2.5)=3. And I can't change anything on the oracle side. So floor won't work

Comment: If the number is something like -2.50000001 it *will* round to `-3`. But -2.5 should round to `-2`. As `2.5` rounds to `3` and `2.499999` rounds to `2`.

Comment: When I run this in oracle XE, I get -3. SELECT ROUND(-2.5) FROM DUAL. Which mathematically is incorrect but that's how it works